# Why doesn't HTMLElement.click() fire mousedown/up?

Tags: javascript, click, mousedown

*Background:* A while ago, I was playing with some simple automation, and wanted to click a `<canvas>`. At first I tried `canvas.click()`, but this didn't work; I realized that the page was listening for `mousedown` events, and `click()` doesn't fire those.

My question is as the title says: Why doesn't [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) fire `mousedown` or `mouseup` events? Its stated and implied goal seems to be to "simulate a mouse-click on an element" – what's the motivation for leaving out this behavior? Simplicity?

Comment: `.click()` doesn’t actually simulate a mouse click and shouldn’t exist. It fires a `click` event and also might submit things. It can’t do `mousedown` and `mouseup` because it doesn’t have position information. Should it also trigger touch events? Anyway, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: Good points. If you compose an answer, I'd accept it.